# why command is canceled when I move terminal window on ubuntu?

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-16.04

everyone!
I installed ubuntu on vmware for working laravel framework.

I have problem with terminal.

when I move terminal window using mouse, running command is canceled.
Please see this...

```
hkg328@hkg328-virtual-machine:~$ ^C
hkg328@hkg328-virtual-machine:~$ ^C
hkg328@hkg328-virtual-machine:~$ ^C
hkg328@hkg328-virtual-machine:~$ ^C
```

whenever I move terminal window using mouse, following line appears in terminal.

```
hkg328@hkg328-virtual-machine:~$ ^C
```

What is the reason?
What should I do for solving this problem?
(When I move terminal using `shift key+mouse drag` It is ok.
But I don't want to use shift key.)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely problem is that your terminal has the xterm mouse-protocol enabled (usually from running some text-editor).  Occasionally that does not clean up after itself (a problem with vim's plugins), and you'll even see this enabled on the shell command-line.

When you click in the text-area without shifting, that sends escape characters (and control characters) when xterm mouse-protocol is enabled.  For xterm, at least, clicking/dragging the window border (including title area) shouldn't pass those escape/control characters to the application.

The use of the shift-key is built into the mouse protocol; if it's enabled you'll get that behavior -- always.

Comment: how can I disable xterm mouse-protocal to prevent command is canceled when I drag terminal window?